# Do I have to start a new game for the Enhanced Edition?

Tags: the-witcher-2

With the [Enhanced Edition of the Witcher 2 just released](http://www.thewitcher.com/community/entry/191), I'm wondering if I need to start a completely new game to experience all the new content?

I started a game a while ago (before the EE was announced) on the dark difficulty and am still in the prologue, am I missing anything if I continue from this save instead of starting from scratch again.

Answer (score 3):

I believe most of the new content is in Chapter 3, so you wouldn't miss much if you just continued from your current save.